# Creating a django form which also uses database data as an option

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-forms, mariadb

My question title isn't very good but what I am trying to create is a way to add students into a database table and in the same form add their parents details into another table.

The problem arises where 2 students have the same parents and I now have two sets of the same parent. Is there a way to select parent from the parent table when I am entering a student?

How would I go about doing this.

Comment: Without some code examples of what you tried and what isn't working, it's difficult to give any specific help.

Comment: And show us your models. You have a one to many relationship between the student and the parent?